# Cloud Firestore Location Recommendation for Philippines

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Firestore and would like to know if choosing the Cloud Firestore Location for my app matters. I'm from the Philippines and my current choices are Mumbai, Hong Kong, Tokyo, Osaka. Any tip or advise would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, service location does matter and in your case, your closest choice is `asia-northeast1 (Tokyo)`

This is from cloud function [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations) and will still apply on other services like cloud firestore.

When selecting what regions to run your functions in, your primary considerations should be latency and availability. You can generally select regions close to your users , but you should also consider the location of the other products and services that your app uses. Using services across multiple regions can affect your app's latency, as well as pricing.